# Can we index graph databases using solr?

Tags: search, indexing, solr, lucene, titan

I need to index a graph database (Titan with Cassandra as back-end), using solr. Can this be done ?

Answer (score 2):

According to its [documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/solr.html), Titan supports using Solr as an indexing backend to do:

- **Full-Text**: Supports all Text predicates to search for text properties that matches a given word, prefix or regular expression.
- **Geo**: Supports the Geo.WITHIN condition to search for points that fall within a given circle. Only supports points for indexing and circles for querying.
- **Numeric Range**: Supports all numeric comparisons in Compare.
- **TTL**: Supports automatically expiring indexed elements.
- **Temporal**: Millisecond granularity temporal indexing.

If you define a [mixed index](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#index-mixed) in Titan that uses Solr as the indexing backend, Titan will place that data into Solr to be indexed. You should still be able to access that data directly through Solr. The examples in the Titan documentation only show how to access the data via the graph because that is what Titan is for: graph. Solr would not be used to store the entire graph data structure, just the contents of the mixed index.

Please refer to the Titan documentation on how to use Titan and Solr together.

Comment: I went through the documentation. According to my understanding, the indexes created using solr as back-end in titan would be used only for search queries in Titan. I want to use the solr webapp to index the data(as we index sql db using data-imports), so that i can provide solr REST services for search on that data. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Solr is just a flat collection of documents. It doesn't care about the relationships between those documents.

This is a slide share of someone who is using Cassandra and Solr together

http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/an-introduction-to-distributed-search-with-cassandra-and-solr

Data is sent to Cassandra which then sends it to Solr for indexing. Solr is supporting full text search of the Cassandra data and this would be a good use case even with Titan in the mix.

Comment: Yes, i'm aware about the flat document constraints. But i want to index the relations as atomic documents(We achieve the same with sql db using joins). We currently maintain the relations in Titan and i'd like to index them. Cassandra is the back-end for Titan, the data and column families in Cassandra are managed by titan. I cannot index them directly.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use Solr as an indexing backend for Titan graph database. There are some different parameters that should be considered for this purpose. These parameters are as follows.

```
# Configure a Solr backend named "search" at localhost:8983
# and path prefix /solr/titan.solr1.
# The collection must already exist -- see the manual for info.
# The indexing backend used to extend and optimize Titan's query
# functionality. This setting is optional.  Titan can use multiple
# heterogeneous index backends.  Hence, this option can appear more than
# once, so long as the user-defined name between "index" and "backend" is
# unique among appearances.Similar to the storage backend, this should be
# set to one of Titan's built-in shorthand names for its standard index
# backends (shorthands: lucene, elasticsearch, es, solr) or to the full
# package and classname of a custom/third-party IndexProvider
# implementation.
#
# Default:    elasticsearch
# Data Type:  String
# Mutability: GLOBAL_OFFLINE
#
# Settings with mutability GLOBAL_OFFLINE are centrally managed in Titan's
# storage backend.  After starting the database for the first time, this
# file's copy of this setting is ignored.  Use Titan's Management System
# to read or modify this value after bootstrapping.
index.search.backend=solr

# The operation mode for Solr which is either via HTTP (`http`) or using
# SolrCloud (`cloud`)
#
# Default:    cloud
# Data Type:  String
# Mutability: GLOBAL_OFFLINE
#
# Settings with mutability GLOBAL_OFFLINE are centrally managed in Titan's
# storage backend.  After starting the database for the first time, this
# file's copy of this setting is ignored.  Use Titan's Management System
# to read or modify this value after bootstrapping.
index.search.solr.mode=http

# List of URLs to use to connect to Solr Servers (LBHttpSolrClient is
# used), don't add core or collection name to the URLS.
#
# Default:    http://localhost:8983/solr
# Data Type:  class java.lang.String[]
# Mutability: MASKABLE
index.search.solr.http-urls=http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

Please be aware that the `"search"` part in the name of these parameters should be same as the index name in your application.